# Why is 'response' not available in the current context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code snippet here. I am trying to refresh the page with `/Events/Index` page when the `Ajax` request is successful. However, inside the `success` method, I see that the `response` variable is available in `else if` case, but it is not available in the `if` case. Inside `if` case, I get an error: `The name response does not exist in the current context`.

The `Ajax` call from the `View` is as follows:

```
$.ajax({ url: "/Events/DeleteEvent", data:data, async: true }).success(function (response) {
    if (response != "" || response != "Event not found!") {
        swal("Deleted!", "The event has been deleted.", "success");
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Events", new { EventId = response })';

    }
    else if (response == "Event not found")
        swal("Cancelled!!!", "Error : " + response, "error");
});
```

This is how I am sending the response to the `success` part of the `Ajax` call from the `Controller`:

```
if (eventid > 0)
{
    ...
    return Json(id);
}
else
    return Json("Event not found");
// id is an integer value that I want to send to success in Ajax.
```

Am I going wrong anywhere?

Comment: The users are never going to see the swal before the window.location line....

Comment: `return Json("Event not found");` why would you not use a key?

Comment: What do you mean by a key @epascarello

Comment: Understood. After reading Tetsuya Yamamoto's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response` is a client-side variable which contains AJAX response, hence you cannot use it as `routeValues` parameter value inside `@Url.Action()` helper which contains server-side code because the script doesn't executed yet while action URL is generated, and `response` variable doesn't declared yet in server-side code.

To fix the issue, try using plain query string to insert `EventId` parameter:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/Events/DeleteEvent",
   data: data,
   async: true,
   success: function (response) {
      if (response !== "" || response != "Event not found!") {
         swal("Deleted!", "The event has been deleted.", "success");

         // use query string because Url.Action helper runs server-side
         window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Events")' + '?EventId=' + response;

      } else if (response == "Event not found") {
         swal("Cancelled!!!", "Error : " + response, "error");
      }
   }
});
```

Or use a placeholder from server-side and then change parameter value to `response` with `replace()`:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/Events/DeleteEvent",
   data: data,
   async: true,
   success: function (response) {
      if (response !== "" || response != "Event not found!") {
         swal("Deleted!", "The event has been deleted.", "success");

         // the URL generated server-side with placeholder
         var targetUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "Events", new { EventId = "xxx" })';

         // replace placeholder with event ID
         window.location.href = targetUrl.replace("xxx", response);

      } else if (response == "Event not found") {
         swal("Cancelled!!!", "Error : " + response, "error");
      }
   }
});
```

**Additional note:**

Better to use client-side property in the response to differentiate between success and error conditions, as provided in example below:

```
if (eventid > 0)
{
    ...
    return Json(new { id = id });
}
else
    return Json(new { message = "Event not found" });
```

**AJAX call**

```
$.ajax({
   url: '@Url.Action("DeleteEvent", "Events")',
   data: data,
   async: true,
   success: function (response) {
      if (typeof response.id !== 'undefined' && response.id != null) {
         swal("Deleted!", "The event has been deleted.", "success");

         // use query string because Url.Action helper runs server-side
         window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Events")' + '?EventId=' + response.id;

      } else if (typeof response.message !== 'undefined' && response.message != null) {
         swal("Cancelled!!!", "Error : " + response.message, "error");
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: I understand. I applied the changes you suggested; even the keys. But upon doing so, there is no action on clicking the `delete` button. In browser, by testing I see that I am getting the following: `Uncaught ReferenceError: DeleteEvent is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (Events:3219)`.

Comment: The `Button` code looks like this: `<a onclick="DeleteEvent('@subevent.EventId', '', @subevent.Parent);">Delete Event</a>`

Comment: You're not defining the `DeleteEvent` function yet, or the function is not in proper scope. Could you provide `DeleteEvent` function contents? Also I preferred `$('#link').click(function () { ... })` over `onclick` event for separation between markup and event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/Events/DeleteEvent",
   data: data,
   async: true,
   success: function (response) {
      if (response !== "" || response != "Event not found!") {
         swal("Deleted!", "The event has been deleted.", "success");
         window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Events", new { EventId = "' + response + '" })';

      } else if (response == "Event not found") {
         swal("Cancelled!!!", "Error : " + response, "error");
      }
   }
});
```

You have some errors in your syntax. Look at the code and you'll see the difference in the syntax.
Let me know how this goes.

Comment: The call from `window.location.href` seems to be reaching `Index.cshtml` page, but the parameter(s) are not reaching. I am getting the following: `http://localhost:5000/Events?EventsId=%27%20%2B%20response%20%27`. When I check the `Controller`, it shows `null` for both the parameters. Code in `Controller`: `public async Task<IActionResult> Index(bool? IsActive, int? EventsId)`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass response value instead of its name

`'@Url.Action("Index", "Events", new { EventId = "' + response + '" })'`